# In my python code, the lines are mixed up

Tags: python

I didn't finish a program in python, then two days later I came back to it and found this.
Does anyone know how this could have happened?
I was coding in Sublime Text

```
                matrix.append(int(a[count_a])) 
                matrix.append(int(vectors[j][i]))
                print(a[count_a], end="")
                print(vectors[j][i], end="")
            count_a2 += 1
            count_first = False
            else:
            if count_a2 == count_tringle:
            out_A.append("("+i+")")
            out_A.append(i)
            out_Ael.append("("+i+")")
            out_Ael.append(i)
            print("+"+vectors[j][i]+"λ"+str(count_alfa), end="")
            print(vectors[j][i]+"λ "+str(count_alfa), end="")
        # entering into the vectors dictionary
        A_str.append(str(i))
        None
        count_a += 1
        count_alfa += 1
        else:
        else:
        else:
        first = False
        for j in keys_list:
        i = str(i)
        if int(i) < 0:
        if int(i) < 0:
        if int(vectors[j][i]) > 0 and count_first is False:
        matrix.append(int(vectors[j][i]))
        opred_matrix_3x3(matrix)
        print(" ", j, end=")
        print("= ", end="")
        print("|", end="")
        print("The matrix is not 3x3, find the determinant yourself")
        print("For example: p 3 -2 4\n "+""*10+"g -2 1 3\n "+""*10+"r 7 -4 1 (in three dimensions)")
        print("Wrong number of characters! Print again\n")
        print()
        print()
        print(vectors[j][i], end=")
        vectors[j[0]] = j[1:]
        x -= 1
    # input
    # output all
    # checks
    # intermediate things
    # let's make the negative intermediate things put in parentheses too
    # let's put negative numbers in brackets
    A_el1 = A[0]*A[4]*A[8]
    A_el2 = A[1]*A[5]*A[6]
    A_el3 = A[3]*A[2]*A[7]
    A_el4 = A[6]*A[4]*A[2]
    A_el5 = A[1]*A[3]*A[8]
    A_el6 = A[0]*A[5]*A[7]
    A_str=[]
    Ael = [A_el1, A_el2, A_el3, A_el4, A_el5, A_el6]
    count_a += 1
    count_alfa = 1
    count_first = True
    count_tringle += 1
    elif 0 == 1:
    else:
    else:
    for i in A:
    for i in A_str:
    for i in Ael:
    for i in x:
    for j in keys_list:
    for j in keys_list:
    for j in vectors[i]:
    global opred_A, out_A
    if dim == 3:
    if first:
    if len(j) != dim+1:
    j = input("")
    j = j.split()
    matrix = []
    opred_A = (A[0]*A[4]*A[8]+A[1]*A[5]*A[6]+A[3]*A[2]*A[7]-A[6]*A[4]*A[2]-A[1]*A[3]*A[8]-A[0]*A[5]*A[7])
    opred_matrix_3x3(matrix)
    out_A = []
    out_Ael = []
    print(" ", i, end="")
    print(" =",a[count_a])
    print(")")
    print("= ", end="")
    print("{}{}*{}*{} + {}*{}*{} + {}*{}*{} - {}*{}*{} - {}*{}*{} - {}*{}*{} =". format(out_A[0], out_A[4], out_A[8], out_A[1], out_A[5], out_A[6], out_A[3], out_A[2], out_A[7], out_A[6], out_A[4], out_A[2], out_A[1], out_A[3], out_A[8], out_A[0], out_A[5], out_A[7]), end= ")
    print("{}+{}+{}-{}-{}-{} = {}\n".format(out_Ael[0], out_Ael[1], out_Ael[2], out_Ael[3], out_Ael[4], out_Ael[5], opred_A))
    print("|")
    print("|", end="")
    print("Δ "+str(count_tringle))
    print("Enter the name of the basis vector and its values with spaces")
    print("The matrix is not 3x3, find the determinant yourself")
    print("⃗"+str(i),"= (",end=")
    print()
    return (A[0]*A[4]*A[8]+A[1]*A[5]*A[6]+A[3]*A[2]*A[7]-A[6]*A[4]*A[2]-A[1]*A[3]*A[8]-A[0]*A[5]*A[7])

# ------------ENTRY------------
# ------------Estage 1------------
# ------------Stage 2------------
# ------------Step 3------------
# dim - dimentional
# Entry
# just a triangle
# triangles with numbers
a = a.split()
a = input("By analogy, enter the data of the decomposable vector\for example: a 25 -15 14\n")
count_a = 0
count_a = 1
count_a2 = 1
count_alfa = 1
count_tringle = 1
def opred(A):
def opred_matrix_3x3(A):
dim = int(input("How many dimensions?\n"))
else:
first = True
for i in a[1:]:
for i in keys_list:
for i in x:
for i in x:
if dim == 3:
input()
keys_list = list(vectors.keys())
matrix = []
print("(number after λ - index λ)")
print(")\n")
print("1)given")
print("\nThe delta triangles")
print("Δ")
print("⃗"+a[0],"= (",end=")
vectors = {} # dictionary of all vectors
while count_tringle <= dim:
while x>0:
x = len(range(1,dim+1))
x = list(range(0,dim))
```

sorry for my pythonish

for stackoverflow:
x x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x x

Comment: it may be IDE issue ,just resolve it by using `select all lines ( CTRL + A ) and then from the menu select Edit → Line → Reindent`

Comment: The file was sorted. I.e. someone ran it through a sort program and replaced it with the result. Notice that the lines are all in lexicographic order. Lines beginning with spaces come first, and at a given indentation level, the first character determines the order, then the second character, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh... maybe I accidentally pressed CTRL + A and f9...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).